# Both a UIImage and a "back" button appearing in my viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have both a UIImage and a "back" button appearing in my viewcontroller and can't figure out why.

here's a screenshot:

[image]

here's my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_back.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];

}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: are you trying to add that UIImage to your backButton?

Comment: yes. just the image and no back button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a backbarbutton item and add a custom to it. Then you define the action for it, where you pop the current view.

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
        UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;


// selector for backButton

-(void)back{
[self.navigationController popViewController];
}
```

Comment: that worked! the -(void)back{} method crashes the app though. any idea why? thanks again

Comment: did you define the method back in your .h file?

Comment: yes. I get a warning: instance method '-popviewcontroller' not found (return type defaults to ID)

Comment: changing it to: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; works great. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom button and add it as a subview of self.navigationController.navigationBar.backBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

The back button is automatic when you push a second view controller into the navigation controller.  You can override it as Andrew Ebling mentioned.  You will need to create a custom UIBarButton item.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image
                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                       target:self
                                                       action:@selector(backEvent:)];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
```